# What is the probability of choosing a vector that is not a linear combination of $k$ independent vectors in $\mathbb{B}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, vector-spaces

What is the probability of choosing a vector that is not a linear combination of $k$ independent vectors in $\mathbb{B}^n$?

My guess is that it can have $n - k - 1$ of its elements as being $0$, so the probability would be $P(\{v \mid v \in \mathbb{B}^n \wedge v \not \in \text{span}(e_1, e_2, ..., e_k)\}) = \frac{2^{n - k - 1}}{2^n} = 2^{-k-1}$. It seems odd that the $-1$ is there. Is this correct?

Comment: What is $\mathbb B$? Which probability distribuition do you use for choosing a vector?

Comment: $\mathbb{B}$ is defined as $\{0, 1\}$. The vector is chosen from a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of vectors in an $m$-dimensional vector space over $GF(2)$ is $2^m$. So the number of vectors not in your span is $2^n-2^k$, and so the probability a randomly chosen vector is not in the span of a given set of $k$ linearly independent vectors $1-2^{k-n}$.